# Prove $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets. Prove $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$ where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of set $A$.

I've tried breaking up $A \cup B$ in various ways, and then using the theorem that if $A$ and $B$ are finite and disjoint then $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B|$, but it didn't seem to work for me.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: One approach is to write $A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)$ and note that the sets on the right are disjoint.

Comment: Another approach is to note that $\max(x,y)+\min(x,y) = x+y$ and apply this to the indicators $1_A,1_B$ and then integrate/sum.

Answer (score 2):

Give every element of $A$ a nice red hat to wear.  Give every element of $B$ an equally nice blue hat.  $|A|$ is the number of red hats given out, and $|B|$ is the number of blue hats.  Adding them is the total number of hats, namely $|A|+|B|$.

Or, we can count differently.  There are $|A\cup B|$ elements with at least one hat.  Many of those elements have just one hat, but some have two hats.  There are exactly $|A\cap B|$ elements with two hats (and none with more than two).  Hence there are $|A\cup B|$ elements with hats, and $|A\cap B|$ extra hats (for those lucky ones with two hats), so $|A\cap B|+|A\cup B|$ hats altogether.